# moderncv: how can I remove the dotfill from subsection?

Tags: moderncv

I am using the `banking` style, and I can't locate any kind of dot-fill in the `subsection`'s command within the `moderncvbody*.sty` or `moderncvstyle*.sty` files.

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}
\homepage{www.myname.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\vspace{5pt}

\subsection{Academic Qualifications}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{2011--2015}{Some title }{Somewhere University}{Over There}{\textit{Some Grade}}{}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image]

And I want to get rid of the dots that appear in the subsection's headline (here: "Academic Qualifications").

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The dot-fill is a feature provided by the document class. Without seeing any working document from you, this might be a little bit tricky to obtain.

Comment: Greetings, thank you for the warm welcome and your comment! I am not sure I understand what you mean; shall I add bits of code in my question?

Comment: Not only bits, a compilable document, please!

Comment: Please strip off your personal information from the document before posting, of course. We aren't interested in your real name, address etc. Just fill in some arbitrary data.

Comment: Yep, this is why it took me so long!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What do you get if you compile the example with xelatex?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've not tested with `xelatex`. I just found that `moderncv` does not use the regular `l@subsection` setup :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B: Update: It does not compile because I don't have FontAwesome fonts installed

Comment: By the way, use of `\cventry` inside `cvitem` is not the intended way, that is the reason why you get the overful box.

Comment: :/
Ah I forgot to mention that the screenshot is the output of LuaLaTeX, I get the same with XeLaTex!

Comment: Oh yes I don't do that thing with \item in mine, this is from a template I found online.

Comment: Don't use templates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `moderncv` is a standalone class, e.g. does not use `\LoadClass{article}` etc. the usual way of getting rid off dots in a `ToC` like style by using `\@dotsep` etc. does not work directly.

The easiest way seems to be 'brute' force

```
 \renewcommand{\subsectionrule}{}
```

Here's the otherwise unchanged code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae} 
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}
\homepage{www.myname.com}

\renewcommand{\subsectionrule}{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\vspace{5pt}

\subsection{Academic Qualifications}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{2011--2015}{Some title }{Somewhere University}{Over There}{\textit{Some Grade}}{}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works!!! :D Thank you! *virtual upvote* since I can't upvote answers yet!

Comment: @Nick: Now you can upvote (and accept the answer, after the grace period) ;-)

Comment: Just did, thanks again for your precious help! =)

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome. If all new users would be as nice as you!!!! I can't upvote again, however

Comment: Haha, thanks for everything! It is people like you that help newcomers get over their hesitations and ask questions! Have a good day!

Comment: @Nick: You too!